# Vincular datos espaciales en Rstudio

Tags: base-de-datos, rstudio

Tengo dos bases de datos. Tabla A con la geometria de "n" puntos y tabla B con la geometría de "z" polígonos ( nombre del departamento  y  geometría.)  . Quisiera en Rstudio agregar una columna en la tabla A que con la etiqueta del polígono al que pertenece el punto.
Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Bienvenido   a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.